# Актуальна-ли в настоящее время разработка проектов на C# 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net

Актуальна-ли в настоящее время разработка проектов на C# 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему нет? Если разрабатывать для WinXP например. Или чтобы портировать на моно, тоже проще жить будет...

Comment: Интересно, сколько процентов windows mobile юзеров осталось еще)

Comment: В индустриальном сегменте очень даже много, основная масса промышленных кпк на WinCE сидят.

Comment: это-то да, но сначала заказы найдите, или работу под 2.0...

Comment: Это другой вопрос :-) Но опять же, в индустриальном сегменте... много кода на двойке или тройке(что по сути та же двойка) который заказчики портировать на новый дот не хочет по причине железяк, стабильности и т.д... Да и не так сильно они отличаются...

Comment: А что такое C# 2.0? .net 2.0 framework я могу еще понять...

Comment: Ну я думаю это и имеется в виду... Хотя есть там изменения... например C# 3.x есть Linq, автопроперти, а в C# 2.0 нет хотя фреймворк у них один - 2.0

Comment: @gecube, не придирайтесь,много кто говорит именно C# version, и даже Вики => http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp
Оба подхода уместны. :))
Спасибо, значит и дальше буду на C# 2.0 писать апивраппер для вконтакте

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, актуально. Хотя, лишаете себя многих вкусных вещей, появившихся в более поздних версиях языка. В частности, анонимные типы, лямбда-функции, инициализаторы объектов, утиная типизация, LINQ, автоматические свойства, методы-расширения и что-то еще, чего уже не помню

Answer (score 1):

На этот вопрос нельзя дать ответ, не прояснив понятие "актуальности"? Что имеется ввиду?

- Стоит ли начинать новый проект на C# 2.0? Нет.
- Стоит ли вкладывать в изучение языка C# 2.0? Не особо.
- Стоит ли изучать IL код, в который компилируется C# 2.0? Можно, там CLR не особо поменялась.
- Стоит ли писать под Windows Forms? Ну, может и стоит, но при чем здесь версия языка...
- Стоит ли писать под .NET 2.0? Это уже более дельный вопрос, но, с другой стороны, почему не использовать .NET 3.5, ведь ядро у него такое же, что и у .NET 2.0.

В общем, если отвечать на более конкретно на абстрактный вопрос, то ответ будет таким: Можно. Но стоит ли? C# - это один из самых активно развивающихся mainstream языков, в чем смысл использовать версию десятилетней давности? Если есть возможность этого не делать, то я бы этого не делал.

Дело в том, что современный C# впитал в себя очень много полезных вещей: там и вещи из функционального программирования, там и отличная библиотека для работы с многопоточностью (TPL, Reactive Extensions), там и поддержка асинхронности из коробки (async/await).

Если есть веские основания лишить себя всего этого, то всегда пожалуйста. Но опыт использования всех этих вещей сделают обладателя этими знаниями значительно более ценным специалистом на рынке труда!

Answer (score 0):

Существует масса легаси-проектов (т.е. созданных давно), работающих на старом фреймворке. И тут скорее нужно говорить про .net версий 2.0 -- 3.5, у них у всех общее ядро -- то же что у .net 2.0. Поэтому получается что такие приложения сравнительно легко проапгрейдить до .net 3.5, но перейти на .net 4.0 -- уже большая проблема, чаще всего -- из-за ряда сторонних компонентов: версию под новый фреймворк нужно покупать, а ресурсов на это нет.

Поэтому, если есть нацеленность на подобный проект -- изучать .net 2.0 *придётся*.